# new Promise not allowing required types from mongo callback

Tags: mongodb, typescript

I have a function that reads from mongo and returns the operation as a promise. The issue I'm facing is that the collection in mongo has a `requiredProp` and `_id` that are `100%` in every record so they are not optional keys. Typescript for some reason is returning an error at runtime (below). I've tried to typescast `result` all the ways I know and nothing worked.

The only thing that did work was adding `?` for both `_id` and `requiredProp`.

Example:

```
export interface MongoRequest {
  _id: MongoObjectId;
  requiredProp: boolean;
  optionalProp?: boolean;
}

async function read (
  query: MongoRequestQuery,
  mongo: any,
): Promise<MongoRequest> {
  const m = mongo.collection(MongoCollections.REQUESTS);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      return m.findOne(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        if (result === null) return reject(new Error(`null mongo ${MongoCollections.REQUESTS}`));
        return resolve(result);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return reject(e);
    }
  });
}

src/MongoRequests.ts (142,5): Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'MongoRequest'.
  Property '_id' is missing in type '{}'. (2322)
```

Why is it that typescript is returning this error at runtime? How can I have required properties in the mongo type?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't know anything about the object you're getting from mongodb. Just add a type-assertion.

Comment: The generic type `T` that goes into `Promise<T>` should be the type of your `result` that you pass to `resolve()`.